# Eclipse creates FrameLayout when creating new project

Tags: android, android-fragments, adt

I've just updated some things on eclipse ADT and I created a new project.

I've seen that in the place where you can set the Main Activity's and main layout's names, now there is another place to set a fragment's name.

When finishing creating the project, in the layout folder now appears the main layout and a framgent layout.

Also, the `mainActivity` extends `ActionBarActivity`, makes a fragment transaction in the onCreate() method, and implements the `PlaceholderFragment` class.

Is there a place where these changes are explained or could someone explain how these modifications affect to coding?

Sorry If this is stupid question, but I'm learning about this and I would like to know how theses changes affect.

Comment: why should they affect your coding? Delete those files and crate new from scratch

Comment: @blackbelt Is not a problem to have those files. I just want to understand if f.e. google has done this to start using fragments and ActionBarActivity because wants to make a transaction towards that, or things like these... just want to understand google's strategy

Answer (score 0):

Those files are template file for an android application using fragments. Like mentioned before you can delete them or use them as you see fit. Fragments are a little different than regular activities and I would recommend reading the android developer guide on fragments if you want to work with these files:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

These will give you an idea of how fragments differ from regular activities.